# Only one LED is working on this traffic light circuit

Tags: breadboard, prototyping

I have a problem with my traffic light circuit. I've made sure of the wiring and everything seems right but for some reason only the yellow LED is lit constantly without it flashing and the other 2 LEDs are not even working. It's my first circuit so I feel a bit lost.

Here are some pictures of my circuit:

[image: I didn't use the 0.1uf]

[image]

Here's the circuit diagram that I'm using:
BTW I didn't use the 0.1uf since I didn't have any
[image]

I've got it from this website [here](http://electronicsclub.info/p_trafficlight.htm)

---

**Edit**

After receiving your answers, I have corrected the breadboard errors.  Now only the red LED is lit.  Here are two new pictures:

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

Comment: I don't see where the red and green LEDs are connected to anything at all.  Check your wiring.

Comment: I somewhat have the feeling you should check how a breadboard is wired...

Comment: What's up with the resistor connected to the green LED? Why does it loop back to itself?

Comment: There's no connection between the 'f' and 'g' rows on a normal breadboard. As such neither your red nor green LEDs are actually connected to anything.

Comment: step one pull everything off the board, step two start over. I see like three huge errors.

Comment: The big capacitor on the left side... is connected to nothing haha

Comment: Give him/her a break, they did say it's their first circuit. In my opinion you should start out simpler, wire a diode to a button and then build from there. Doing that would have made finding out that the understanding of breadboard wiring is wrong and easier to fix.

Comment: The problem though is that it would take more to fix the wiring than it would starting over from scratch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are misunderstanding the way a breadboard is wired internally.  Check out [this](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-breadboard-and-build-a-led-circuit--mac-54746) link for information.

Here is an image, taken from that link:

[image: breadboard]

One issue you have, as an example, is the resistor connected to your green LED.  Both leads are plugged into a single node, and therefore it doesn't act to bring power to your LED (or do anything at all).

To see what I mean, look at this next image. All the holes marked by the green line are connected, and the blue holes are also connected.  However, there is no connection through the red line.  The green and blue lines *aren't* connected to each other.

[image: example]

---

**Edit:**

Regarding your modified circuit, the breadboard corrections look good. Here's what else I see:

1. You'll need to connect all the power busses together (and the ground busses).  Often, this simply requires putting a wire from the V+ rail on one side to the V+ rail on the other side, and again for the ground busses.  However, as RJR points out (*see his comment below*) it appears that your breadboard has multiple power busses along each edge ("V3", "V4", etc).  If these are, in fact, not connected to each other, then you'll have to do it with wires.
2. The diode from pin1 of the 4017 appears backwards.
3. You'll want to check the polarity of your LEDs.  I can't tell from the pictures if they are oriented correctly.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm very new to all of this so thank you that was very helpful.

Comment: @Sarah_b Glad to help :)

Comment: I've fixed the errors. I'm not sure if there's any other error but now only the red LED is lit. If you can take another look at my circuit I'd really appreciate it!  [Pic1](http://postimg.org/image/imcki0gev/) - [Pic2](http://postimg.org/image/xtnyomivr/)

Comment: @Sarah_b I added your new pictures to your original question, and have updated my answer. Good luck!

Comment: Also note that the 'busses' at each end (labeled V1, V2 etc. form the looks of it) are not connected. At least it seems the holes with the red line are connected - so 1-14, 17-30, etc.). The black line leads me to believe that those holes are all connected though. Tip: get a cheapo multimeter and try it out!

Comment: @RJR Great catch!  I agree.  I'll add it up above :)

Comment: wow thank you so so much!! I've learned a lot from you all. My circuit is finally working. Thank you again!

Comment: @Sarah_b Congrats!  One last thing: the 0.1uF cap smooths out power glitches that occur when you hook up you battery to the circuit.  It's important that it's there.  Since you don't have any 0.1uF, I would recommend using one of the 1uF caps if you have any more.  Google "decoupling capacitor" for a lot of good information. Have fun :)

Comment: I've added it :) Thank you a million times! I truly appreciate you taking the time to help me out. I have one last question to ask, sometimes when I connect the battery only the red LED will work but if I try to connect the battery again the circuit will work just fine. Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: @Sarah_b Hmm, that sounds like the problem that the 0.1uF decoupling capacitor was trying to fix.  The 1uF cap that you added should help with the problemn - did you put it in the right direction?  One possible problem is that the electrolytic type of capacitors that you are using aren't the best for decoupling.  Ideally, you would use a ceramic (as opposed to electrolytic) capacitor in the 0.1u to 1.0u range.  The difference is that the electrolytic caps have a much higher ESR (equivalent series resistance) than the ceramics, and so they can't handle voltage spikes as quickly.

Comment: @Sarah_b Another thing to know is that electrolytics are generally polarized, whereas ceramic caps can be installed in either orientation.  This is shown in the schematic; look at the difference between the 0.1uF cap symbol and the other cap symbols.  Most schematics don't show this difference, however, so don't learn to expect it :)

Comment: Aha .. it makes sense. Well, I think it's in the right direction regarding the positive and negative.. Umm.. can take a look [Here](http://postimg.org/image/gmjfes9tt/) . Thank you  :) also sorry for bothering you so much but all of this has been really helpful for me

Comment: @Sarah_b Yes, that looks correct.  The thick line running down one edge of the capacitor marks the lower-potential side.  You might try putting another 1uF in parallel to the first one.  It will increase the capacitance even more, but it will also lower the ESR.  Other than that, I'd try a ceramic cap!  Glad to answer your questions. Take care!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this section of your first picture: -

[image]

Red and green LEDs are unconnected.

Answer (score 0):

See the line that dips in the middle of the board that cuts of the two sides as such the resistor thats supposed to be connected to the RED LED is not since there is a gap between it extend the resistor over the gap OR move the LED up and connect a wire from the LED to the voltage rail (i think you connected it to 0v ?)