# Circuit simulation for audio equalizer not working need help debugging

Tags: circuit-design, breadboard

For a personal project I was designing a basic audio equalizer circuit using this online simulation tool called TinkerCad.

I managed to build the circuit but for some reason I really can't get it to work.

I think it has to do with the fact I connected multiple breadboards and I may not have connected them properly (I had to do this because you cannot shorten the lengths of resistors on TinkerCad.)

Attached below are the screenshots of the circuit diagram, and a snapshot of the breadboard.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So how does it not work? How have you debugged what is wrong? Which op amp are you using? But have you even connected power supplies to the opamps?

Comment: hm, I think if you need  multiple breadboards, you've simply long outgrown tinkercad.  Why transform your perfectly fine schematic into a "would never actually build this on breadboard if the simulation is working" work-intense tinkercad simulation? Just transfer your circuit into any of the free SPICE simulators, and do a proper simulation.

Comment: Honestly, I did it on spice it works perfectly fine but for the project I'm required to run it on tinkercad.

Comment: @Justme, do I still need to supply power to the op amps? and also the simulation does not work at all.

Comment: @KarryAlams Do you think electronics work without power supply? That might be the reason why the simulation does not work. Or then simulation simplifies the power supply and it is implicit in the simulation. But still, which op-amp model you are using? And can you describe in which way the simulation does not work at all? What component values did you use? And why is Tinkercad required - is this school project or homework?

Comment: @Justme. It's a 741 op amp. I'm sorry I thought supplying the wave using the frequency generator was enough.

Comment: @Justme I have attached a powersupply to the circuit but there still appears to be issue with it. Do i need to attach power to each op amp individually?

Comment: What kind of power supply? Does it supply both a positive and a negative rail as well as a ground? Or just a positive and a ground?

Comment: The power supply has only positive and ground.

Comment: your problem is a duplicate of this one [Only one LED is working on this traffic light circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/166314/only-one-led-is-working-on-this-traffic-light-circuit)

Comment: Note the op-amp power pins are also missing from the schematic.  Each 741 has a + and - supply. Note the 741 is a very low-performance part, and it's output will only go to about 2v shy of its supply rails.  (Do some searching here about the 741 to learn more.)

Comment: 741 will work with expected  2 V headroom loss to rails.

Answer (score 0):

The simulation does not work because the op-amp power supply pins are not connected to a power supply.

Answer (score 0):

Change all the DC grounds on Op Amps and resistors to Vcc/2 with 2 R’s with unity gain buffer for a single supply. Add cap.